# How do you list all users in firebase firestore function

Tags: javascript, function, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have been learning firebase firestore functions and I wanted to list all users and have then compare a value to that they have stored. Such as if there are 20 users and I want to see all users named "mike" how can I get an array of the users so I can compare them so I can find all users name "mike"?

I am running:

```
"firebase-admin": "^5.11.0",
"firebase-functions": "^1.0.0"
```

I saw this snippet of code for firebase admin but I dont thing it works as it wasn't labeled a firestore function, but if it does if I return the "admin.auth().listUsers..." will I get an arraylist of users?

```
    function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        console.log("user", userRecord.toJSON());
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken)
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: The code you show (from [this documentation section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) for those interested) shows precisely how to get an array of users from Firebase Authentication. It does however have nothing to do with Cloud Firestore, nor does it have anything to do with Cloud Functions for Firebase. If you want to get a list of users, I suggest you first try to run this code in a local Node.js script and then work up from there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but how would i get that to connect to the functions in the cloud

Comment: I strongly recommend taking it one step at a time. First get it working on a local Node.js system. Once you have that working and you're ready to move it to Cloud Functions so you can call it from you app, have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I done it:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp()

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const listUsers = await admin.auth().listUsers()

        return res.status(200).send({ listUsers })
    } catch (err) {
        return handleError(res, err)
    }
})

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

this shows a list of users but still need some work to make it better

**Update**

```
    exports.getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
    var allUsers = [];
    return admin.auth().listUsers()
        .then(function (listUsersResult) {
            listUsersResult.users.forEach(function (userRecord) {
                // For each user
                var userData = userRecord.toJSON();
                allUsers.push(userData);
            });
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(allUsers));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error listing users:", error);
            res.status(500).send(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: why not use   res.json(data)

Comment: @SuperUberDuper actually I changed the code to this :
exports.getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
    var allUsers = [];
    return admin.auth().listUsers()
        .then(function (listUsersResult) {
            listUsersResult.users.forEach(function (userRecord) {
                // For each user
                var userData = userRecord.toJSON();
                allUsers.push(userData);
            });
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(allUsers));
        })
}

Comment: its only return first 1000 users

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do that search with the function `getUserByDisplayName()`. 
You can see it in this Firebase guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users. But as Frank said that has nothing to do with `firebase-functions.` It is a part of Firebase Auth.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thats for the sdk not api